# This is my first time programming in VBA, I do not get any return values for MolarVolume

Tags: vba, excel

no matter what I plug in, I get a Value error #Value! Is there a problem with the way my function is written, used to C++ and Matlab. Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. This is a function to calculate the Molar Volume of a compound from 3 different Datasets for different Values. The logic In my opinion (feel free to correct) seems to be fine. It's just that I am not used to the Visual Basic Syntax. If there are any logical or syntax related errors please please please tell me. All help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
Function MolarVolume(compund As String, T As Double, P As Double) As Double
T = 273.15 + T
Dim Compare As String
Dim Z01 As Double  
Dim Z02 As Double
Dim Z0 As Double
Dim Tc As Double
Dim Pc As Double
Dim Z11 As Double
Dim Z12 As Double
Dim Z1 As Double
Dim Pr As Double
Dim Pr1 As Double
Dim Pr2 As Double
Dim col As Integer
Dim Row As Integer
Dim ComparePressureZ As Double
Dim CompareTempZ As Double

Set Data = Worksheets("data").Activate

Compare = Data.Cells(Row, 1)


While Compare <> compound
Row = Row + 1
Compare = Data.Cells(Row, 1)
Wend

Tc = Data.Cells(Row, 4)
Pc = Data.Cells(Row, 5)

Tr = T / Tc
Pr = P / Pc  

Tr = Round(Tr, 1)


Set Dataz0 = Worksheets("data_Z0.csv").Activate

col = 1
Row = 1


ComparePressureZ = Dataz0.Cells(1, col)
CompareTempZ = Dataz0.Cells(Row, col)

While ComparePressureZ < Round(Pr, 1)
col = col + 1
Pr1 = Dataz0.Cells(1, col)
While CompareTempZ <> Tr
Row = Row + 1
Wend
Z01 = Dataz0.Cells(Row, col)
Wend



Set Rng = Range("B1:P1")
Row = 1
col = 2


For Each cll In Rng
If cll.Value > Pr Then
col = col
Pr2 = Dataz0.Cells(1, col)
Else
col = col + 1
End If
Next


While CompareTempZ <> Tr
Row = Row + 1
Wend


Z02 = Dataz0.Cells(Row, col)


Z0 = Z01 + (Pr - Pr1) * ((Z02 - Z01) / (Pr2 - Pr1))


Set dataz1 = Worksheets("data_Z1.csv").Activate

col = 1
Row = 1

ComparePressureZ = dataz1.Cells(1, col)
CompareTempZ = dataz1.Cells(Row, col)

While ComparePressureZ < Round(Pr, 1)
col = col + 1
Pr1 = dataz1.Cells(1, col)
While CompareTempZ <> Tr
Row = Row + 1
Wend
Z11 = dataz1.Cells(Row, col)
Wend



Set Rng = Range("B1:P1")
Row = 1
col = 2


For Each cll In Rng
If cll.Value > Pr Then
col = col
Pr2 = dataz1.Cells(1, col)
Else
col = col + 1
End If
Next


While CompareTempZ <> Tr
Row = Row + 1
Wend


Z12 = dataz1.Cells(Row, col)


Z1 = Z11 + (Pr - Pr1) * ((Z12 - Z11) / (Pr2 - Pr1))


MolarVolume = Z1


End Function
```

Comment: Step through the code using F8. Where does it break?

Comment: I'll save you the trouble: If you're calling this as a user-defined function *from the worksheet*, it cannot be done this way. You can't use the `Activate` method (and in fact, you can't use many of the `Range` methods within a UDF called from the worksheet). Ranges should be passed as arguments to the function.

Comment: Here's some other stuff you can't do in a UDF too - [UDF limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787#mt1)

Comment: Thank You for the response, if not for a UDF how can I run through this?

Comment: Is the following of any help? [Calculating Molecular Weight Using Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050976/calculating-molecular-weight-using-excel)